# The coproduct of a family of objects of a Preorder (seen as a category)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

If the coproduct of a family of objects of a Poset (seen as a category) is the least upper bound,

> who is the coproduct  of a family of objects of a Preorder (seen as a category)?

My intuition tells me that is the lub again but I'm having trouble writing the proof formally due to it is my first time with category theory and I'm not a mathematician, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, it is the least upper bound. The proof is the same, except for some fiddling with equality.

Answer (score 2):

A preorder is essentially a category $\cal P$ whose hom-sets $\mathcal P(x,y)$ have at most one arrow $x\to y$, which then represents the relation $x\le y$, otherwise the hom-set is empty.

The coproduct of a family of objects $(x_i)_i$ is an object $s$ such that $x_i\le s$, and the universal property is just $s$ being the **least** upper bound, i.e. whenever $y\ge x_i$ for each $i$, then $y\ge s$. The equality $(x_i\to s\to y)=(x_i\to y)$ is automatic since there's at most one arrow between any two objects.

Note that the uniqueness of arrows is also the reason for that the coproduct $s$ is also the *colimit* of any diagram with the same object set $(x_i)_i$, essentially because adding arrows doesn't add any information/conditions to the diagram and its colimit.

Comment: This is very very VERY old so my apologises but I have a quick question, would you happen to know what the product in a preorder would be? or if there is any?

Comment: @ZelosMalum: The product of a family of objects $(x_i)_i$ is the largest lower bound of that family, it need not exist, even if the family is finite. In a total order it will exist for any finite family, or for any bounded family if the order is complete.

Comment: so coproduct always exists but product does not for a preorder or partially ordered set?

Comment: @ZelosMalum. No, that's not correct. Note that the concepts are completely dual, that means if you change the order by reversing all relations (so $x\ge y$ when originally $x\le y$), then the coproduct becomes the product and vice versa. So the coproduct need not exist either.

Comment: Ah, alright. What would the criteria be for such to exist?